# Discrepancy in the transformation law for the Christoffel Symbols of the First Kind

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

I'm currently studying Tensor Analysis from *Mathematical Methods: For Students of Physics and Related Fields* by Sadri Hassani.

In page 462, he introduces the "Affine Connection", i.e., the Christoffel symbols of the second kind as a set of three-indexed symbols $\Gamma^{j}_{mp}$ that obey the following transformation law:

$$ \bar{\Gamma}^{j}_{mp} = \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l}\frac{\partial x^h}{\partial \bar{x}^m}
\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \Gamma^{l}_{hk} - \frac{\partial^2\bar{x}^j}{\partial x^h \partial x^k}\frac{\partial x^h}{\partial \bar{x}^m}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \tag{1}$$

In pages 465-466, he proceeds to introduce the "Metric Connection", i.e., the Christoffel symbols of the first kind as the unique, torsion-free affine connection defined as:

$$
\Gamma^{j}_{kl} = \Gamma^{j}_{lk} = \frac{1}{2}g^{jm}\left (\frac{\partial g_{mk}}{\partial x^l} + \frac{\partial g_{ml}}{\partial x^k} - \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^m} \right) \tag{2}
$$

In one of the exercises listed at the end of the chapter (Exercise 17.22), he asks the reader to verify that the metric connection given by $(2)$ is indeed an affine connection by verifying that it transforms according to $(1)$.

Upon attempting to do this, I arrived at the following transformation law for the metric connection:

$$
\bar{\Gamma}^{j}_{mp} = \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \frac{\partial x^h}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \Gamma^{l}_{hk} + \frac{\partial^2 x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \tag{3}
$$

To me, this is clearly a different transformation law than $(1)$ because the second order terms don't match and no matter what I do, I cannot get those terms to match. I verified $(3)$ via external sources, namely:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Transformation_law_under_change_of_variable
- https://www.general-relativity.net/2019/03/transformation-of-christoffel-symbol.html

So my result seems correct. But I don't understand why there is this discrepancy in the transformation law. Do the Christoffel symbols of the first kind not obey $(1)$ or is $(1)$ even the correct transformation law for affine connections? Any clarity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These are the same: use the chain rule and you can show this in a few lines. This has been asked on here before iirc.

Comment: @Eletie Hi, I found the related question you were referring to and following your hint there, I was able to bridge both the expressions. Thanks a lot :) I'll mark this question as duplicate and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the expressions are equivalent, and thanks to @Eletie I found that the same question has been asked before: [Transformation of Christoffel Symbol](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/626145/transformation-of-christoffel-symbol?rq=1)

Following the hints that @Eletie provided there I was able to answer my question and bridge the gap between the two expressions. For my own future reference and for others who stumble upon this, I will outline my answer below:

Consider the second term in $(3)$,

$$
\frac{\partial^2 x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l}
$$

We can rewrite this as,

$$
\frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \left ( \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \right )
$$

If we consider this as being one part of a product derivative, then the product derivative it corresponds to is given by the product rule as,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \left( \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \right) = \frac{\partial^2 \bar{x}^j}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial x^l} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} + \frac{\partial^2 x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l}
$$

Where the second term on the right is the second term in $(3)$.

By the chain rule,

$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \left( \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \left( \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \right)
$$

But,

$$
\frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial \bar{x}^p} = \delta^j_p
$$

So,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \left( \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \delta^j_p = 0
$$

Therefore,

$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= \frac{\partial^2 \bar{x}^j}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial x^l} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} + \frac{\partial^2 x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \\
\implies \frac{\partial^2 x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} &= - \frac{\partial^2 \bar{x}^j}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial x^l} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p}
\end{align*}
$$

Rewriting by employing the chain rule,

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} &= - \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \left ( \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \right ) \\
&= - \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial x^h}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^h} \left ( \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} \right ) \\
&= - \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial x^h}{\partial \bar{x}^m}\frac{\partial^2 \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^h \partial x^l}
\end{align*}
$$

Relabeling dummy index $l \rightarrow k$,

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 x^l}{\partial \bar{x}^m \partial \bar{x}^p} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^l} &= - \frac{\partial^2 \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^h \partial x^k} \frac{\partial x^h}{\partial \bar{x}^m} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^p}
\end{align*}
$$

Which is precisely the second order term in $(1)$.